# Best way to storing large immutable data from custom query job

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

After running a job based on a customer query eg,

```
SELECT user_id FROM table1 where <conditions>
INTERSECT / INTERSECT ALL
SELECT user_id FROM table2 where <conditions>
```

I would like to store the user_id into a table which will be used in the future in this manner,

```
SELECT [attributes1, attributes2, attributes3] FROM table1 where user_id IN (...user_ids)
```

I am thinking what would be the best way to store the user Ids, the userIds will not be used in any query except for the example above, it's immutable and cleared within 10 days

**Option1**: Two tables with one to many relationship

Job Table: `jobId, total_results, runDate`

Job Result Table: `jobId, user_id`

**Option2**: Single table with longtext for results, comma delimitered user_id

Job Table: `jobId, total_results, runDate, user_ids`

Would it be better to use option1, or option2?